# How to split column by delimiter on Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, delimiter

I've a column of emails and I'd like to split it into two columns using `@` as a delimiter.

Table:

[image]

Expected outcome

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [SPLIT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split) with subsequent [OFFSET](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#offset_and_ordinal):

```
SELECT SPLIT(email, '@')[OFFSET(0)] as email1, SPLIT(email, '@')[OFFSET(1)] as email2
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```sql
select split(email, "@")[ofsset(0)],split(email, "@")[ofsset(1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider yet another [non-orthodox and maybe even silly but hopefully fun and exposing some extra features of BigQuery] approach

```
select * from (
  select * from your_table, 
  unnest(regexp_extract_all(email, r'[^@]+')) piece with offset 
)
pivot (min(piece) as email for offset in (0, 1))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: love it! thank you!